# How to get the auto generated RestApi from my AWS SAM template? To use in another SAM template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I used AWS SAM to generate my Lambda/APIs. But I want to be able to get this  RestApi so I can use it in another SAM template.

The idea is to have 1 base infra CloudFormation/SAM template that creates the network, ALB, API Gateway things

Then each "micro-service" will have its own SAM template and it will create API endpoints referencing this "root" RestApi by specifying the `RestApiId` attribute

Is this a correct approach? Wonder if when I deploy each service, will it remove the APIs for the other services?

Answer (score 1):

You can access default auto generated RestApi as  `ServerlessRestApi`. This is logical resource id for auto generated RestApi resource.

`ServerlessRestApi` access example in `template.yaml` is as follows.

```
Outputs:
  ApiRootURL:
    Description: API Root URL
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${ServerlessRestApi.Stage}"
```

You can see `ServerlessRestApi` in the resource list of you CloudFormation stack. `ServerlessRestApi` is not documented, so it might be changed in the future version.